# this.id on an Element Event Listener becomes an array of all id's of elements clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event listener on all textboxes. When a textbox is clicked, I'd like to open a keyboard. On Enter of the keyboard I'd then like to use the id of the textbox which called it to do some logic. However the id (txtbxId in code) just becomes the first textbox I click, then the second textbox I click in an array.
 E.g, the alert becomes 'textbox1' - after second textbox click alert is 'textbox1' 'textbox2' 
I've tried to force the variable id to '',  to delete it etc. to no avail,
Code snippet here:

```
$('.textbox').click(function() {            
  var txtbxId = this.id;
  $("#Keyboard").show();

  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) { 
      alert(txtbxId);                 
    }
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're nesting events. Therefore as well as duplicating the `keydown` event when a click event happens, you're supplying each individual `id` to those events.

To fix this, use a single event handler for all the `.textbox` elements, and read their own `id` from the reference to the element which raised the event which is available through the `this` keyword:

```js
$('.textbox').click(function() {
  $("#Keyboard").show();
});

$(document).on('keydown', '.textbox', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    alert(this.id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `on('keydown')` function the first time you click a textbox never gets unassigned, so for every time you click a .textbox, you're making a NEW keydown callback, but not removing your old ones.

I would recommend making an object outside of your onClick callback which manages .keydown callbacks, so that you only have one at any time.

Something like this:

```
window.keydownmanager = {
  init: () => {
        $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
                        window.keydownmanager.callback(e);
        });
  },

  callback: () => {},

  setCallback: (cb) => {
    window.keydownmanager.callback = cb;
  }
}
```

And inside your onClick callback, do this:

```
var txtbxId = this.id;

$("#Keyboard").show();
window.keydownmanager.setCallback(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) { 
    alert(txtbxId);                 
  }
})
```